# A simple quadrilateral is a parallelogram if:

Tags: geometry

1) Opposite sides are congruent

2) opposite angles are congruent

3) one pair of opposite sides are congruent and parallel

4) the diagonals bisect each other

How can I proof this with congruency?

I was thinking I make a parallelogram ABCD. If I can show triangle ABC and CDA are congruent, then I can prove 1 and 2.

And also making a point that intersects AC and BD I can use congruency to prove triangle APB and CPD congruent.

I am bit confused how to show point 3?

Comment: What is your *definition* of a parallelogram? Are you really trying to prove that if one of these conditions holds, they all do?

Comment: My definition is a convex quadrilateral whose opposite sides are parallel.

Comment: Well, if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, then by 1), opposite sides are congruent, so 3) follows. Are you trying to prove that if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram then 1)-4) hold, or that if any of 1)-4) hold then $ABCD$ is a parallelogram?

Comment: I'm trying to prove if it's a parallelogram then 1 and 4 hold. 

Also I was going about proving one at a time, and I did end up proving 1, just not the other ones.

Comment: Well, if you've proven 1, then you've proven 3.